# $1 + {\alpha}^2 + 2 \alpha \cos(\omega)$ as a square of distance

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to prove that

$$ 1 + {\alpha}^2 + 2 \alpha \cos(\omega) = |1 - \alpha e^{-j\omega}|^2$$

starting from

$$ 1 + {\alpha}^2 + 2 \alpha \cos(\omega)$$

(That is, no backwards proofs of multiplying out $ |1 - \alpha e^{-j\omega}|^2$ to see that it matches $1 + {\alpha}^2 + 2 \alpha \cos(\omega)$.)

Comment: Look for the roots of this second degree polynomial in $\alpha$.

Comment: Just do the 'backward' proof in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

assuming $\alpha$ is a real number (not complex):

$$1-2 \alpha cos(\omega)+|\alpha|^2 $$
$$1-2 \alpha \frac{1}{2} (e^{j\omega}+e^{-j\omega})+|\alpha|^2$$
$$1-\alpha e^{j\omega} - \alpha e^{-j\omega} + \alpha^2 e^{j\omega}e^{-j\omega}$$
$$(1-\alpha e^{j\omega}) - \alpha e^{-j\omega}(1-\alpha e^{j\omega})$$
$$(1-\alpha e^{j\omega})(1-\alpha e^{-j\omega})$$
$$|1-\alpha e^{j\omega}|^2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use $$\alpha^2=\alpha^2(\cos^2\omega+\sin^2\omega)$$and substitute.